# Decoupling Frontend from Django backend?

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I have a website and I have the front end (HTML,CSS and JavaScript) separate from the backend. What I want to do is pull data from the backend, however, if I don't do this from the same one as the Django backend I get a Cross Origin error.

What's the best way to implement this? PJSON? CORS? or am I approaching it wrong? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm handling it with [django cors headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers). You can see a live example [here](https://github.com/arpheno/eestecnet/blob/master/eestecnet/settings/conf/cors.py#L1).

Basically all you need is:

```
  CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'google.com',
    'hostname.example.com'
)
```

Comment: How are you accessing the data from the front end from there? Are you using jQuery's "getJSON" ? Because I can't seem to get it to work using "getJSON". Cheers

Comment: I'm using angulars "$resource" unfortunately.